# Direct network access (ethernet) to RaspPi2 from PC Linux

Tags: networking, pi-2, ethernet

I try to setup an access from my PC Linux (Debian jessie 64 bits) to  my new Raspberry-Pi2. (The image is a distro generated by Yocto).

My PC-Linux is connected to the internet on wlan0. I had no ethernet cable connected to my internet box before.
My network config on linux is:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 34:17:eb:e0:c1:31  
          inet addr:172.17.15.0  Bcast:172.17.15.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:75 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:75 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:7621 (7.4 KiB)  TX bytes:7621 (7.4 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:19:34:b5:df:bf  
          inet addr:192.168.0.47  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::8219:34ff:feb5:d8bc/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:56855 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:36714 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:31888490 (30.4 MiB)  TX bytes:6393979 (6.0 MiB)
```

On my Rpi, content of the /etc/network/interfaces:

```
iface eth0 inet static
          address 172.17.15.5
          netmask 255.255.0.0
```

But it does not work.
Even worse, after reboot, `ifconfig` does not display eth0.

My network knowledge are limitted and I can't point out what's wrong in the net config or raspberry config.

Z.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is the list above on the Pi? If not what does it show? Your attempt to set a static address will not work. See  http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697

Comment: Can you `ping 172.17.15.0` from your pi?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on the Linux side from the looks of it. 172.17.15.0 is not a valid address. The last number must be between 1 and 254. (172.17.15.255 is set as your broadcast address, although it really should be 172.17.255.255 based on the subnet mask.)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "auto eth0" to your /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 172.17.15.5
netmask 255.255.0.0
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: This will not work. If you read the comment at the top of `/etc/network/interfaces` this is noted. See  http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697